# Android SQLite: How to ensure consistency in batch upload and delete upon success if no unique key is given?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a SQLite table on Android.
The table does not have a unique key.

The goal is to do the following:

1. Define and get a batch of rows from the table (e.g., 100 rows). The rows can be selected randomly.
2. Upload the data and receive a success note. During the upload process, new rows are added to the table.
3. Delete the batch of rows from the table upon success
4. Repeat steps 1 to 3 until the table contains fewer rows than a given threshold.

How can step 1 (define and get batch of rows) and step 3 (delete this batch from database) be implemented in Android Java SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `Transaction` in DB, the one way to ensure about status of huge operations with DB. It's first thing, you need to be familiar with. You can check [this resource, for ex](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-transaction/). In samples, you could find it's implementation with pure SQL syntax, however it could be possible with Android and Java, with something like below.

```
/**
 * Open DB somehow
 */
db.beginTransaction();
try {
     /**
      * Select your N records from DB
      */

     /**
      * Perform any other action and Delete from DB
      */
} catch {
     /**
      * Handle Exception and Do Rollback
      */
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```